# when i try to get req.user using nestjs with jwt it always returns the same user no matter if i changed user

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, nestjs

when i try to get req.user using nestjs with jwt it always returns the same user no matter if i changed user.
For example, if I am with user2 or user3, it always returns user1.

How do I get req.user to return the current user and not always the same user as it happens now?

I leave you the files of my authentication module with jwt:

app.module.ts:

```
import { Module, CacheModule } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthModule } from "./auth/auth.module";
import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { EnvConfiguration } from "./config/env.config";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import { redisStore } from "cache-manager-redis-store";
import { ProjectModule } from "./project/project.module";
import { NewModule } from "./new/new.module";
import { ApplicationModule } from "./application/application.module";
import { ProfileModule } from "./profile/profile.module";
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';

@Module({
    imports: [
        AuthModule,
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            load: [EnvConfiguration],
        }),
        MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGODB),
        CacheModule.registerAsync<any>({
            isGlobal: true,
            useFactory: async () => {
                const store = await redisStore({
                    socket: { host: process.env.REDISDB, port: Number(process.env.REDISPORT) },
                    ttl: Number(process.env.REDISTTL),
                });
                return {
                    store: () => store,
                };
            },
        }),

        ProjectModule,
        NewModule,
        ApplicationModule,
        ProfileModule,
        UserModule,
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

auth.module.ts

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { AuthController } from "./auth.controller";
import { JwtAccessTokenStrategy } from "./strategies/jwt.access-token.strategy";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import { JwtModule } from "@nestjs/jwt";
import { JwtRefreshTokenStrategy } from "./strategies/jwt.refresh-token.strategy";
import { UserModule } from '../user/user.module';

@Module({
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [AuthService, JwtAccessTokenStrategy, JwtRefreshTokenStrategy],
    imports: [
        UserModule,
        ConfigModule,
        JwtModule.register({}),
    ],
    exports: [],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

auth.controller.ts

```
import { Body, Controller, Get, Post, Put, Req, UseGuards } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { Request } from "express";
import { AccessTokenGuard } from "./guards/jwt.access-token.guard";
import { AuthAccessToken } from "./decorators/auth.access-token.decorator";
import { ValidRoles } from "./enums/valid-roles";
import { RefreshTokenGuard } from "./guards/jwt.refresh-token.guard";
import { AuthRefreshToken } from "./decorators/auth.refresh-token.decorator";
import { AuthUserDto } from "./dto/auth-user.dto";
import { RefreshTokenDto } from "./dto/refreshtoken-dto";

@Controller("auth")
export class AuthController {
    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

    @Post()
    authenticateUser(@Body() AuthUserDto: AuthUserDto) {
        return this.authService.authenticateUser(AuthUserDto);
    }

    @UseGuards(AccessTokenGuard)
    @AuthAccessToken(ValidRoles.user)
    @Get("logout")
    logout(@Req() req: Request) {
        return this.authService.logout({ id: req.user["_id"] });
    }

    @UseGuards(RefreshTokenGuard)
    @AuthRefreshToken(ValidRoles.user)
    @Put("refresh")
    refreshTokens(@Body() refreshTokenDto: RefreshTokenDto) {
        return this.authService.refreshTokens(refreshTokenDto);
    }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, CACHE_MANAGER, Inject, ForbiddenException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { JwtService } from "@nestjs/jwt";
import { IJwtPayload } from "./interfaces/jwt-payload.interface";
import { Cache } from "cache-manager";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { ObjectId } from "bson";
import { IUserResponse } from "./interfaces/user-response.interface";
import { IJwtTokenInterface } from "./interfaces/jwt-token.interface";
import { handleException } from "src/common/helper/exception.helper";
import { UserService } from "src/user/user.service";
import { User } from "src/user/entities/user.entity";
import { AuthUserDto } from "./dto/auth-user.dto";
import { RefreshTokenDto } from "./dto/refreshtoken-dto";

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
        private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
        private usersService: UserService,

        @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER)
        private readonly redis: Cache,
        private configService: ConfigService,
    ) {}

    authenticateUser = async (authUserDto: AuthUserDto): Promise<IUserResponse> => {
        try {
            const userCached = await this.checkUserInCache(authUserDto.publicKey);

            if (userCached) {
                return userCached;
            }

            const userLogued = await this.checkUserLogued(authUserDto.publicKey);

            if (userLogued) {
                return userLogued;
            }

            return await this.registerUser(authUserDto);
        } catch (error) {
            handleException(error);
        }
    };

    private async checkUserInCache(publicKey: string): Promise<IUserResponse> {
        let userCached: User = await this.redis.get(publicKey);

        if (userCached) {
            userCached = JSON.parse(userCached.toString());
            const tokens = await this.getJwtTokens({ id: userCached._id });
            await this.updateRefreshToken({ id: userCached._id }, tokens.refreshToken);

            userCached.refreshToken = tokens.refreshToken;
            await this.redis.set(userCached.publicKey, JSON.stringify(userCached));
            return <IUserResponse>{ ...userCached, accessToken: tokens.accessToken };
        }

        return null;
    }
    private async checkUserLogued(publicKey: string): Promise<IUserResponse> {
        const userAuthenticated = await this.usersService.findOneByPublicKey(publicKey);

        if (userAuthenticated) {
            delete userAuthenticated.__v;
            delete userAuthenticated.isActive;

            const tokens = await this.getJwtTokens({ id: userAuthenticated._id });
            await this.updateRefreshToken({ id: userAuthenticated._id }, tokens.refreshToken);

            userAuthenticated.refreshToken = tokens.refreshToken;

            await this.redis.set(publicKey, JSON.stringify(userAuthenticated));

            return <IUserResponse>{ ...userAuthenticated, accessToken: tokens.accessToken };
        }

        return null;
    }

    private async registerUser(authUserDto: AuthUserDto): Promise<IUserResponse> {
        const user: User = await this.usersService.create(authUserDto);

        delete user.__v;
        delete user.isActive;

        const tokens = await this.getJwtTokens({ id: user._id });
        await this.updateRefreshToken({ id: user._id }, tokens.refreshToken);
        user.refreshToken = tokens.refreshToken;

        await this.redis.set(authUserDto.publicKey, JSON.stringify(user));

        return <IUserResponse>{ ...user, accessToken: tokens.accessToken };
    }

    private getJwtTokens = async (payload: IJwtPayload): Promise<IJwtTokenInterface> => {
        const objectId = new ObjectId(payload.id);

        const [accessToken, refreshToken] = await Promise.all([
            this.jwtService.signAsync(
                { id: objectId },
                {
                    secret: this.configService.get<string>(AuthEnum.JWT_ACCESS_SECRET),
                    expiresIn: AuthEnum.EXPIRE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                },
            ),
            this.jwtService.signAsync(
                { id: objectId },
                {
                    secret: this.configService.get<string>(AuthEnum.JWT_REFRESH_SECRET),
                    expiresIn: AuthEnum.EXPIRE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
                },
            ),
        ]);

        return { accessToken, refreshToken };
    };

    async refreshTokens(refreshTokenDto: RefreshTokenDto): Promise<IJwtTokenInterface> {
        try {
            const user = await this.usersService.findOneById(refreshTokenDto.id);

            if (!user || !user.refreshToken) throw new ForbiddenException("Access Denied");

            const refreshTokenMatches = await bcrypt.compare(refreshTokenDto.refreshToken, user.refreshToken);

            if (!refreshTokenMatches) throw new ForbiddenException("Access Denied");

            const tokens = await this.getJwtTokens({ id: user._id });
            await this.updateRefreshToken({ id: user._id }, tokens.refreshToken);

            user.refreshToken = tokens.refreshToken;
            await this.redis.set(user.publicKey, JSON.stringify(user));
            console.log("TOKEN REFRESH UPDATE SUCESFULL")
            return tokens;
        } catch (error) {
            handleException(error);
        }
    }

    private updateRefreshToken = async (payload: IJwtPayload, refreshToken: string) => {
        const salt = 10;
        const hashedRefreshToken = await bcrypt.hash(refreshToken, salt);
        await this.usersService.update(payload.id, hashedRefreshToken);
    };

    logout = async (payload: IJwtPayload) => {
        try {
            const user = await this.usersService.update(payload.id, null, false);
            await this.redis.del(user.publicKey);
        } catch (error) {
            handleException(error);
        }
    };
}
```

jwt.access-token.strategy.ts:

```
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from "passport-jwt";

import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { IJwtPayload } from "../interfaces/jwt-payload.interface";
import { UserService } from "src/user/user.service";
import { User } from "src/user/entities/user.entity";

@Injectable()
export class JwtAccessTokenStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, "jwt_access_token") {
    constructor(private configService: ConfigService, private usersService: UserService) {
        super({
            secretOrKey: configService.get("JWT_ACCESS_SECRET"),
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: IJwtPayload): Promise<User> {
        const { id } = payload;

        const user = await this.usersService.findOneById(id);

        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Token not valid");
        }

        if (!user.isActive) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("User is inactive, talk with and admin");
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

jwt.refresh-token.strategy.ts:

```
import {PassportStrategy} from '@nestjs/passport';
import {ExtractJwt, Strategy} from 'passport-jwt';
import {Request} from 'express';
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {ConfigService} from "@nestjs/config";
import { UserService } from 'src/user/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class JwtRefreshTokenStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt-refresh-token') {
    constructor(private configService: ConfigService, private usersService: UserService) {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            secretOrKey: configService.get('JWT_REFRESH_SECRET'),
            passReqToCallback: true,
        });
    }

    async validate(req: Request, payload: any) {
        const refreshToken = req.get('Authorization').replace('Bearer', '').trim();
        const {id} = payload;

        const user = await this.usersService.findOneById(id);
        user.refreshToken = refreshToken
        return user
    }
}
```

jwt-payload.interface.ts:

```
export interface IJwtPayload {
  id: string;
}
```

jwt-token.interface.ts:

```
export interface IJwtTokenInterface {
    accessToken: string
    refreshToken: string
}
```

user-response.interface.ts

```
import { IExperience } from "src/profile/interface/experience.interface";
import { ISkill } from "../../profile/interface/skill.interface";
export interface IUserResponse {
    _id: string;
    publicKey: string;
    fullName?: string;
    profilePicture?: string;
    nick?: string;
    email?: string;
    accessToken?: string;
    refreshToken: string;
    roles: string[];
    hasAirdrop: boolean;
}

export interface IUserProfileResponse {
    _id: string;
    publicKey: string;
    fullName?: string;
    profilePicture?: string;
    nick?: string;
    email?: string;
    accessToken?: string;
    refreshToken: string;
    roles: string[];
    hasAirdrop: boolean;
    skills: ISkill[];
    experiences: IExperience[];
}
```

jwt.access-token.guard:

```
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {AuthGuard} from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class AccessTokenGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt_access_token') {
}
```

jwt.refresh-token.guard.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {AuthGuard} from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class RefreshTokenGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt-refresh-token') {
}
```

user-role.guard.ts

```
import { Reflector } from "@nestjs/core";
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable, BadRequestException, ForbiddenException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { META_ROLES } from "../decorators/role-protected.decorator";
import { User } from "src/user/entities/user.entity";

@Injectable()
export class UserRoleGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const validRoles: string[] = this.reflector.get(META_ROLES, context.getHandler());

    if (!validRoles) return true;
    if (validRoles.length === 0) return true;

    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = req.user as User;

    if (!user) throw new BadRequestException("User not found");

    for (const role of user.roles) {
      if (validRoles.includes(role)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    throw new ForbiddenException(`User ${user.fullName} need a valid role: [${validRoles}]`);
  }
}
```

valid-roles.ts:

```
export enum ValidRoles {
    admin = "admin",
    superUser = "super-user",
    user = "user",
}
```

authEnum.ts:

```
const enum AuthEnum {
    JWT_ACCESS_SECRET = "JWT_ACCESS_SECRET",
    JWT_REFRESH_SECRET = "JWT_REFRESH_SECRET",
    EXPIRE_ACCESS_TOKEN = "5s",
    EXPIRE_REFRESH_TOKEN = "7d",
}
```

auth-user.dto.ts:

```
import {IsOptional, IsString} from "class-validator"

export class AuthUserDto {

    @IsString()
    publicKey: string;

    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    refreshToken: string
}
```

refreshtoken-dto.ts:

```
import { IsNotEmpty, IsString } from "class-validator";

export class RefreshTokenDto {
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    id: string;

    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    refreshToken: string;
}
```

auth.access-token.decorator.ts:

```
import {applyDecorators, UseGuards} from '@nestjs/common';
import {ValidRoles} from '../enums/valid-roles';
import {UserRoleGuard} from '../guards/user-role.guard';
import {RoleProtected} from './role-protected.decorator';
import {AccessTokenGuard} from "../guards/jwt.access-token.guard";


export function AuthAccessToken(...roles: ValidRoles[]) {

    return applyDecorators(
        RoleProtected(...roles),
        UseGuards(AccessTokenGuard, UserRoleGuard),
    );

}
```

auth.refresh-token.decorator.ts:

```
import {applyDecorators, UseGuards} from '@nestjs/common';
import {ValidRoles} from '../enums/valid-roles';
import {UserRoleGuard} from '../guards/user-role.guard';
import {RoleProtected} from './role-protected.decorator';
import {RefreshTokenGuard} from "../guards/jwt.refresh-token.guard";


export function AuthRefreshToken(...roles: ValidRoles[]) {

    return applyDecorators(
        RoleProtected(...roles),
        UseGuards(RefreshTokenGuard, UserRoleGuard),
    );

}
```

role-protected.decorator.ts:

```
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ValidRoles } from '../enums/valid-roles';


export const META_ROLES = 'roles';


export const RoleProtected = (...args: ValidRoles[] ) => {


    return SetMetadata( META_ROLES , args);
}
```

user.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { User, UserSchema } from "./entities/user.entity";
import { UserService } from "./user.service";

@Module({
    controllers: [],
    providers: [UserService],
    imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }])],
    exports: [UserService, MongooseModule],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

user.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectModel } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Model } from "mongoose";
import { User } from "./entities/user.entity";
import { ObjectId } from "bson";
import { AuthUserDto } from "src/auth/dto/auth-user.dto";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(User.name)
        private readonly user: Model<User>,
    ) {}
    async create(authUserDto: AuthUserDto):Promise<User> {
        return (await this.user.create(authUserDto)).toObject();
    }

    async findOneByPublicKey(publicKey: string): Promise<User> {
        return this.user.findOne({ publicKey: publicKey }, { __v: 0 }).lean();
    }

    async findOneById(id: string): Promise<User> {
        const objectId = new ObjectId(id);
        return this.user.findOne({ __id: objectId }, { __v: 0 }).lean();
    }

    async update(id: string, refreshToken: string, logged = true) {
        const objectId = new ObjectId(id);
        return this.user.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: objectId },
            { refreshToken: refreshToken, logged: logged },
            { returnOriginal: false },
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is it that `req.user` is always the same? That's a lot of code above to look through